# Best practice for executing timed actions in Android

Tags: android, handler, android-handler, android-runtime

In a specific part of my code in need to run 3 actions in a a timed space, right now i am using this method:

```
Handler mHander = new Handler();


public void startChainActions(){

// do first action
      mHandler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
          @Override
          public void run() {

          //do action 2

                    mHandler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {

                    //do action 3
                    }
                  }
                }, 1500);

              }
             }
            }, 5000);
           }


public void cleanResources(){

    mHandler.removeCallbacksAndMessages(null);
    mHandler==null
}
```

When using this method i often see this message on my logcat:

```
W/art﹕ Suspending all threads took: 12.272ms
```

which leads me to believe it is slowing down performance.
is there a better way to time actions after each other?

Comment: Could you explain us why it is necessary that there is a "sleep" between the execution of the methods?

Comment: Have you tried using a CountdownTimer?

Comment: The reason is that i need to use AnimationDrawble on a view, using two animations with finite time and have the last one run infinitly, so the first run finishes, the second one replaces it, then that one finishes, and the third infinite one starts, i have not tried using CountdownTimer, is that any better? what is the difference?

Comment: Will an `AnimationSet` help ? http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/animation/AnimationSet.html

Comment: I am using AnimationDrawbles, not Animations...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all you should understand that in case of Handlers you will execute Runnable in the same thread where handler was created. It means that you will share hardware power with any user<->UI interaction if you run it in a main thread, and there is no guarantee on exact time of execution start.

Answering your question from body - no, there is no slowing down of performance because of 2 `postDelayed` calls, but could be because of your actions. So your log message is connected with something else.

**Update:**
Answering your question from title: if you'd like to run delayed action, than yes - it's a normal way to do it in Android, especially if you'd to run it in main/UI thread.

Comment: this chain of actions however accrues lots of times in the space, (could accrue up to 2 times a second) is that still not reason enough for performance problem? there is no user interactions on this app, only animations running, most of which are AnimationDrawbles

Comment: Chain of action itself do not cause performance issue, actions do.

Comment: Thank you,  this helps me understand some things,  but to answer the title of the question (so that i can accept this as the correct answer), is this a best practice way to commit timed actions in android\java?

Comment: If you'd like to run delayed action, than yes - it's a normal way to do it in Android, especially if you'd to run it in main/UI thread. Hope it answer your question.

Answer (score 0):

Can we not use `SingleThreadExecutor` as below.

```
ExecutorService animationQueue = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();

animationQueue.submit( new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        // action 1
        Thread.sleep(5000);
    }
});

animationQueue.submit( new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        // action 2
        Thread.sleep(1500);
    }
});

animationQueue.submit( new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        // action 3
    }
});
```

Comment: I can, however i wish to use handlers for the case where i need to remove all the callbacks from it (and there could be alot on it) and handler gives me the easy option of removeAllCallBacksAndMessages(null).
i was just wondering if what i am doing is a hack or a correct way to do this

Comment: @ZivKesten same cleanup for Executors is done with `shutdownNow` method.

Comment: Is this  better method in your opinion?

Comment: @ZivKesten I won't tell better in terms of performance. But in terms of readability, I will tell far cleaner.